# How to display a text in textbox by tapping/clicking the two buttons (combined)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I've done layouting my android application, the problem now is that, how could I combine the two buttons, like when I click the **first block and the 3rd block** that will generate a associate "letter" So basically in every combination of buttons there is a **corresponding "letter"**

Or please do correct me if I'm wrong if using a "button" to implement what I wanted is the right thing to use? If not, please state what's the right way to do to implement what I wanted.

[image]

If I haven't explain well, I would state some examples: For e.g clicking the 1st block, 3rd block and the 5th block that generates a letter "z".

Please pardon me if my explanation is confusing. Sorry I am still learning java.

Comment: so basically you have created the buttons from a-z and on the click of each button you have to form letter based on their values ??

Comment: @eLemEnt yes indeed sir.

Comment: @eLemEnt combination of buttons* that depends on the letter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create your layout with all the `buttons` and respective ids and values for example I am giving you one button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

just like this create `buttons` with respective ids and text values...

Now inside your activity `setOnClickListener` for all buttons.

inside your `onCreate()`

like this

```
Button A = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA);
Button B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB);
.
.
.
.   just like this
```

then `setOnClickListener`

```
A.setOnClickListener(this);
B.setOnClickListener(this);
```

After this inside your `onClick()` method just based on the which button clicked append their value to a string. and first declare one global string variable for example `String letter;`

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnA:
                 letter += "A";  
                 break;
            case R.id.btnB:
                 letter += "B";  
                 break;
            .
            .
```

Hope this will help

> Ok so now I am editing my answer...

m just gonna give you small idea depending on that you have to decide

so as per your question what you want is suppose user press `btnA` and `btnB` you want to write z on the screen. This is not a simple job you its actually lengthy. First of all you have to decide on what combination you want to generate what just like btnA and btnB you need to generate `z`

so keep your clicks same as i have given above just inside your `onClick` function change the code that I am giving you.

so first

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnA:
                 letter += "A";
                 checkCombo(letter);  
                 break;
            case R.id.btnB:
                 letter += "B";
                 checkCombo(letter);  
                 break;
            .
            .
```

So now create one function named as `checkCombo(String letter)` with one `string` parameter

Now the actual part comes where you have to decide what combinations you want so if you want on A and B clicks to generate `Z` then create a switch case like below

```
function checkCombo(String mletter) {
  String generatedLetter;
  switch(letter) {
    case "AB":
     generatedLetter = 'Z';// or you can set it to your textview here
     letter = ""; // if it goes inside any of your switch case clear your 
                     global variable
     break;
    case "DEF":
     generatedLetter = 'P'
     letter = "";
     break;
  }

}
```

This is just a lengthy solution but will work

Comment: I appreciate the will to help, I am very grateful, but for now I can't test those codes, since I am still in the office. I will now note that in the meantime, and will try as soon as I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: Hello sorry for the late response, there is something that I am currently doing right now before this. But I am bit confused about the **"letter += "A";** So when I pressed the "btnA" it will generate "A" in the textbox right ? 

And what if I click "btnA" and "btnB"? let's assume that's btnA is 1st block and btnB is 2nd block. If I tap those on android screen (combined) Like 1stblock + 2ndblock to generate letter "Z" how is that possible? 

Thank you really for the help.

Comment: @pjforum then you have to decide on what combinations you have generate which characters depending on that you display data

Comment: If you don't mind, can you "edit" and add an example below? Thank you. :) In every tap of generate characters it will display on the textbox. :)

Comment: I can't seem to get. Pressing the btnA and btnB generate separate characters. I want if I click the btnA + btnB it will generate a letter (one character). Please do help me with this one.

Comment: Is that means you have to click them together or one after another

Comment: One after another. :) For e.g: clicking the btnA then btnB it will generate just "one letter". **single touch** not **multi touch** sir.. :)

Comment: Aight, thankss I'll check it out... In the mean time I'll send you what I'm aiming.. https://youtu.be/wQE870a_S3k?t=1m35s

Comment: I don't seem to understand why I'm having "Invalid character constant" in the function **checkCombo** the **AB and  DEF** when I tried to change them in other variable. The error would go into the switch**(letter)**

Comment: @pjforum sorry actually that is a string so please inside switch rather than using ' use "" so case "AB": or case "DEF" ..

Comment: Hello sir, I don't get any response. They aren't combining.. Anyways have you seen the video? https://youtu.be/y3jJa-mlN9c?t=1m16s this is what I am aiming for sir.

Comment: Hello sir first of all you've been a great help on my improvements.. May I ask a question? How about making a function from A-Z to implement the braille alphabets, using buttons ? Is that applicable ? This one is the last that I am lacking of, When I am done of this my application would on be its 100% working.. please hoping you could help me of this..

Comment: Hello sir I think I have explain very well here on my other post, hope you can check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t

Answer (score 0):

Get the button id on click and do your logic like below
First set onClickListener for all buttons then onClick method do like this

```
 @Override
 Public void onClick(View v){
 switch(v.getId()) {
 case R.id.first_button_id:
 case R.id.second_button_id:
 case R.id.third_button_id:
 String value = "your character";
 break;
  }
```

Comment: I see, so separate codes in every letter? Because sometimes there are a combination of two, three, four or even five buttons to generate a corresponding **"letter"**

Comment: That is up to you finally. Or you can setTag your corresponding letter in your respective button view and get  your corresponding letter through getTag() method in you button view inside onClickMethod