# Android: Tapping one to six buttons continuously [one after another] to string together different results

Tags: java, android, eclipse, function, switch-statement

I have decided to work on an Android app that uses very similar technology to that of an app I have seen before. I wanted to string together multiple button presses to equate to different a different text result.

[Six dots - braille application (actual application to use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAIC4.jpg)

This native braille app I am making has 6 different buttons that I would like to have every unique combination bring me different letters. For example: I would like hitting button 1 to simple bring me the letter "A". Then hitting button 1 and button 2 continuously brings me the letter "C". I want every different button combination of these 6 buttons to bring me a seperate letter.

Can someone who is proficient at Java please explain how this is done? How can I string in multiple button presses to bring me to a different result? Thanks for the help.

[Braille alphabet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFf5.jpg)

My code on java:

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);

          Window window = this.getWindow();
          window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
          window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
          window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

          // Init GUI
          txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
          Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
          Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
          Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block3);
          Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block4);
          Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block5);
          Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block6);



          // Attached Click Listener
          btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

          buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
          buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
          buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
          buttonFour.setOnClickListener(this);
          buttonFive.setOnClickListener(this);
          buttonSix.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        }

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.block1:       

             break;
        case R.id.block2:

             break;
        case R.id.block3:

            break;
        case R.id.block4:

            break;
        case R.id.block5:

            break;
        case R.id.block6:

            break;
        }
     txtMessage.setText();
    }

    //functions below.
    ....     ....
    ...       ...
    ..         ..
    .     O     .
    ..         ..
    ...       ...
    ....     ....
```

---

On my XML Layout `keyboard.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/lightgrey">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMesssage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Enter Message"
    android:textColor="@color/darkbrown" >
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="Button two" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/bg_gradient_end"
        android:text="Button three" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey"
        android:text="Button four" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey"
        android:text="Button five" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@color/bg_gradient_start"
        android:text="Button six" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code that I have made so far is not working as I wanted it to, so I leave the `switch` statement blank for now. Please correct me on my codes or help me with this one. Thanks

My timer code:

```
            Timer processTimer = new Timer();
        processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1), "A");
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1) + getString(R.id.block2), "C");



            }
        }, 500); // Delay before processing. 

    processTimer.cancel();

    processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.get(R.id.block1);
                map.get(R.id.block1+R.id.block2);
                //this.close();


            }
        }, 500);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: are you going to implement an "enter" button? (to register a sequence of your 6 buttons) or do you want the app to automatically accept a sequence after a pause?

Comment: @TWL Hello good day, no enter button needed. I want that the app to automatically accept a sequence after a pause. :)

Comment: What about binary sum? button 1 = 100000b, button 2 = 010000, button 3 = 001000b, button 4 = 000100b, button 5 = 000010 and button 6 = 000001. When press button 1 and button 2 just add 100000b and 010000b the result is 110000b. Make constant: 110000b = 'c'. Button 1 + Button 4 is 100000b + 000100b = 100100b = 'e'. Do u know what I mean?

Comment: @aptyp holy christ, I am not following.. I don't get it really, sorry I am not that proficient in java programming really. But that sounds cool, though does there any conflicts if I have to work from A-Z letters?


**EDITED:** I don't think If I have to generate letters from A-Z that doesn't work..

Comment: @aptyp That kinda works, but wouldn't allow for double of a button within a sequence since you're basically just or'ing the data. You also can't tell what buttons was first.  So button1 then button2 == button2 then button1. that's no good.

Comment: @TWL Hello sir, was hoping if you know how to process the input using hash map? Just like the answer below.. I am getting errors, when I tried.

Comment: If you don't know how to do Hashmaps: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm or you don't know how to convert/translate that data to letters https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFf5.jpg ?

Comment: @TWL I already have some codes using hashmap but it isn't working :X And yes I am having hard time converting the data to letters :X I tried before using switch it works, but not the way it should be. So they said the option is to use `Array List - Sequence` or `Hashmap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to code with a method that similar to the suggestion by aptyp:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
static long DELAY_TIME_INPUT = 500;
static int INPUT_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
static int INPUT_TYPE_CAP = 1;
static int INPUT_TYPE_NUM = 2;

TextView txtMessage;
int[] mAlphabetTable1 = new int[]{1, 3, 9, 25, 17, 11, 27, 19, 10, 26,
                                5, 7, 13, 29, 21, 15, 31, 23, 14, 30,
                                37, 39, 58, 45, 61, 53};
int[] mSymbolTable1 = new int[]{2, 6, 4, 18, 36, 40, 50, 22, 38, 52, 54, 12};
/* Note: The value used below {8, 16, 20, 24} are just an example.
    I choose these values because they are not defined on the above tables.
  */
int[] mSpecialTable1 = new int[]{8, 16, 20, 24};

// char[] mAlphabetTable2 = new char[]{};
char[] mNumberTable2 = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
char[] mSymbolTable2 = new char[]{',', ';', '\'', ':','-', '.', '.', '!', '“', '”','(','/'};
int mCurrentAlphabet = 0;
int mCurrentInputType = 0;
long mLastTimeStamp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    // Init GUI
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block3);
    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block4);
    Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block5);
    Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block6);
    // Attached Click Listener
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFour.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFive.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSix.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.block1: mCurrentAlphabet |=1; break;
        case R.id.block2: mCurrentAlphabet |=2; break;
        case R.id.block3: mCurrentAlphabet |=4; break;
        case R.id.block4: mCurrentAlphabet |=8; break;
        case R.id.block5: mCurrentAlphabet |=16; break;
        case R.id.block6: mCurrentAlphabet |=32; break;
    }
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    Button btView = (Button) view;
    btView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mLastTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(currentTimeStamp - mLastTimeStamp > DELAY_TIME_INPUT){
                genNewBrailleAlphabet();
            }
        }
    }, DELAY_TIME_INPUT + 10);
}

public void genNewBrailleAlphabet(){
    if(mCurrentAlphabet == 32 || mCurrentAlphabet == 60){ // Check if input is Cap or Num sign?
        if(mCurrentAlphabet == 32){ // Input is Cap sign.
            mCurrentInputType = INPUT_TYPE_CAP;
            TextView txtCap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cap);
            txtCap.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else { // Input is Num sign.
            TextView txtNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num);
            if(mCurrentInputType == INPUT_TYPE_NUM){
                mCurrentInputType = INPUT_TYPE_NORMAL; // Turn off Num sign.
                txtNum.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            } else {
                mCurrentInputType = INPUT_TYPE_NUM; // Turn on Num sign.
                txtNum.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    } else { // Input is not Cap or Num sign.
        byte currentAlphabetIndex = -1;
        char newAlphabet = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mAlphabetTable1.length; i++) {
            if (mAlphabetTable1[i] == mCurrentAlphabet) {
                currentAlphabetIndex = (byte) i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(currentAlphabetIndex != -1) { // Check if input is Numbers or Alphabets?
            if (mCurrentInputType == INPUT_TYPE_NUM) { // Input is Numbers.
                if(currentAlphabetIndex < 10) {
                    newAlphabet = mNumberTable2[currentAlphabetIndex];
                }
            } else if (mCurrentInputType == INPUT_TYPE_CAP) // Input is Alphabets.
                newAlphabet = (char) (currentAlphabetIndex + 'A');
            else newAlphabet = (char) (currentAlphabetIndex + 'a');

            String msg = txtMessage.getText().toString() + newAlphabet;
            txtMessage.setText(msg);
        } else { // Input is not Numbers or Alphabets.
            for (int i = 0; i < mSymbolTable1.length; i++) {
                if (mSymbolTable1[i] == mCurrentAlphabet) {
                    currentAlphabetIndex = (byte) i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(currentAlphabetIndex != -1) { // Check if input is Punctuations?
                newAlphabet = mSymbolTable2[currentAlphabetIndex];
                if(currentAlphabetIndex == 8){ // Open Quote, Question Mark have the same pattern.
                    String tmpString = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                    if(tmpString.length() > 0 && !tmpString.endsWith(" ")){
                        // Last typed alphabet is not space, so this is Question Mark.
                        newAlphabet = '?';
                    }
                }
                String msg = txtMessage.getText().toString() + newAlphabet;
                txtMessage.setText(msg);
            } else { // Input is not Punctuations, so it is Special Action or undefined.
                for (int i = 0; i < mSpecialTable1.length; i++) {
                    if (mSpecialTable1[i] == mCurrentAlphabet) {
                        currentAlphabetIndex = (byte) i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(currentAlphabetIndex != -1) { // Check if input is Special Action?
                    String msg = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                    // Input is Special Action
                    switch (currentAlphabetIndex) {
                        case 0: // Change focus here
                            // Change focus code
                            /* if (txtNumber.hasFocus()) {
                                txtMessage.requestFocus();
                            } else {
                                txtNumber.requestFocus();
                            } */
                            break;
                        case 1: // BackSpace
                            msg = msg.substring(0, msg.length() - 1);
                            txtMessage.setText(msg);
                            break;
                        case 2: // Space
                            msg = msg + " ";
                            txtMessage.setText(msg);
                            break;
                        case 3: // New Line
                            msg = msg + "\n";
                            break;
                    }
                    txtMessage.setText(msg);
                } else { // Input not defined.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked button combination not defined!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        if(mCurrentInputType == INPUT_TYPE_CAP){
            TextView txtCap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cap);
            txtCap.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mCurrentInputType = INPUT_TYPE_NORMAL;
        }
    }
    // Reset button views ana variable for next alphabet.
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block3);
    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block4);
    Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block5);
    Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block6);
    buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonThree.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonFour.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonFive.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonSix.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    buttonOne.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonThree.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonFour.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonFive.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonSix.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    mCurrentAlphabet = 0;
}}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_weight="4.0"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMesssage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/darkbrown" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:text="CAP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/cap"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button one" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button two" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button three" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:text="Num"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button four" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button five" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/block6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Button six" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that I am using handler instead of timer. Hope it help!

Comment: +1 This also works, this is much more good than the previous answer. But more complicated, may I ask? Where did you initiate the generating of letters?

Comment: Because I want to add `comma`, `question mark`, `punctuation mark`, `exclamation point`, `new line`, `backspace`, and `space` @I_A_Mok

Comment: Btw I want to add this on `if (txtNumber.hasFocus()) {
               txtMessage.requestFocus();
          } else {
              txtNumber.requestFocus();
          }` but the thing is when I add in 'switch: case R.id.block4' everytime I clicked/tapped the `R.id.block4` it move to the other editText [vice-versa]. PS: I have two editTexts.. Do you know where to put this **"code"**

Comment: Edited answer on display numbers which should give you more hints on coding about the symbols. About the EditText, is the focus not changed? or the one focused is not the one you expected? In addition, could you tell why there are 2 EditText and need to switch focus?

Comment: Okay thank you, and may I know where did you implement the alphabets? I would like to modify some of them, is that possible? And about the EditText, the focus is changed, but whenever there is a combination that includes `R.id.block4` it will move to other EditText. And the reason why there is 2 EditText and need focus is that the end-user are blinds. So they just rely on "voice command".

Comment: Edit answer on detecting R.id.block4. This solution has a limitation that the first clicked/tapped button cannot be R.id.block4 when entering alphabets or numbers. I think you can make a better solution when you have code the symbols, you can make change of focus in one of the case of symbols. Alphabets are from ASCII, you can see 'A' and 'a' in the code. Replace them with an array and do things similar to numbers.

Comment: Okay thank you, I've done in `Focus`, well, how to (how do I say this) like when I click the "numbers" which is 3,4,5,6 it will always generate numbers unless I again click 3,4,5,6 (block)?

Comment: Edited genNewBrailleAlphabet(). Hope it help :)

Comment: Should I implement a local variable namely `mSymbolTable1 and 2?` Idid implement but it's not wokring..

Comment: That is for you to make your tables of symbols later. You can comment out the whole else{} block at present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133177/discussion-between-pjforum-and-i-a-mok).

Answer (score 1):

I don't write a lot of java, so I can only give you psuedocode, but I'll point you in the right direction.

To finish this you only have about 3 things to do:
1. Collect your input data (the button taps), which you've almost done.
2. Know when it's time to process the input.
3. Process the input to the right output.

1. Collect your input.
   At this point you want to store those presses in an array of id's, switch not necessary.  After a few presses you should have array of inputs.

   inputs[R.id.block1, R.id.block2, R.id.block2];
2. Know when it's time to process.
   In your button press handler, add a countdown timer. With every button press, cancel the timer and start a new one.

   ```
   Timer processTimer = new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {    processInput();    }
       }, 500); // Delay before processing. 


   processTimer.cancel();
   processtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {    processInput();    }
       }, 500);
   ```

When processInput() is called you know the user has stopped pressing buttons.

3. Process the Input.
   Create key/value pairs for your outcomes.

   ```
   map = {[R.id.block1],'A',
       [R.id.block1, R.id.block2],'B',
       [R.id.block1, R.id.block2, R.id.block2],'C',
     etc...
   }
   ```

   Search it for the user's input and get your value.

That's basically all there is to it.

Comment: Darth is on the right path; you will need to save your button clicks into an array that matches your braille alphabet; set up a timer to listen for that pause; then a logic to translate that array into a character.

Comment: Hello sir darth, I am a bit confused as where to "store those presses" in #1. and in #2 by "button press handler" where that can be located ? Sorry I am really not good.

Comment: @pjforum The array would be declared somewhere that onCreate() and onClick() can get at it; wherever you're storing your application/class state. In onCreate(), initialize it; in onClick() add to it; and in processInput() empty it after saving/processing, to clear the input buffer.

Comment: yes I've tried declaring the "inputs[R.id.block1,R.id.block2, R.id.block3,R.id.block4,R.id.block5,R.id.block6];" on onCreate(), but I am getting this error *Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression*

Comment: Oh damn, anyways I have initiated on my onClick() already. But when I try to import the TimerTask I get  
        - **Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Timer**
 - **TimerTask cannot be resolved to a type**
 - **The method schedule(TimerTask, Date) in the type Timer is not applicable for the arguments (new TimerTask(){}, int)**

Comment: So what I did was separate the Timer processTimer = new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() into Timer processTimer=new Timer(); processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(); it's all good now.. Well for the "processing of input" where to put that sir ?

Comment: processInput() would go at the same level as onClick and onCreate.

Comment: Okay I have initiated the #2 to onClick and onCreate(), how about the #3 sir? Where to put the **map = {[R.id.block1],'A',
    [R.id.block1, R.id.block2],'B',
    [R.id.block1, R.id.block2, R.id.block2],'C',
  etc...
}**

Comment: The map can be local to the processInput() function.

Comment: Yes I've tried that @DarthNoodles but I am getting errors. These are the errors: **-(1)Syntax error on token "{", Expression expected after this token
 -(2)Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens**

Comment: Once again, that's psuedocode.  Google how to create a map in java.

Comment: @DarthNoodles oh damn I am also not very proficient in java coding. Though I have imported libraries and declared **" Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); "** already.. May I ask a question? The #1 and #2 is already done right (no errors) ? so now I have to deal in #3 yes ?

Comment: I believe I have done the #1 and #2.. But I am not getting the #3.

Comment: You'll want a map with one type the character/String you're defining, the other an Array to store the input that matches. My Java is too rusty to give actual code, lookup some examples of HashMaps and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @DarthNoodles Ok I've been trying but I am not getting it.. I will work hard on it. Thank you so much. I will checked the "marked as answer" as soon as I get this.

Comment: @pjforum, i've read through this and I have a few questions related to what you want to do. when you say 'continuously' do you mean sequentially, or do you mean at the same time? eg push button1 then button2, or push button1 and button2. Are you only planning support the alphabet, or want to support numbers and special characters? I also believe that aptyp (in first block of comments) was on the right track as long as pressing button1 + button2 is the same as pressing button2 + button1. Is this the case?

Comment: @heater Hello first of all, thank you for taking some of your time reading my post.. And well what I mean by 'continuously', it could be sequentially. **push button 1 then button 2**, well yes sir indeed. I want to support numbers and as well as special characters. In the case of *aptyp* I don't think it will work, since there are some letters that is in need of 4 buttons, even 5 buttons, like clicking `btn1 then btn3 then btn4 then btn5 - to generate a letter`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I have given this a go, and I believe this will help you get down the path you are attempting given my current understanding of your requirements. I have been quite verbose in my commenting of the class, what I am doing, and why. I hope it is helpful and doesn't feel like pandering. It sounded maybe you were pretty new to Java and Android and I felt the added explanation might be useful.

I am sure there are edge cases and bugs that have been missed, but should be a good start.

**Android Activity Class -- MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

/**
 * TAG is typically used for the Log class if you want to see debug/error information in logcat
 */
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Constant to delay before attempting to resolve button presses to an input
 */
public static final int INPUT_HANDLE_DELAY_MS = 500;
/**
 * Buttons have naming convention button<column><row>
 */
private Button mButton00;
private Button mButton10;
private Button mButton01;
private Button mButton11;
private Button mButton02;
private Button mButton12;

/**
 * Where we are going to store the input generated by button presses
 */
private EditText mEditText;

/**
 * Where the lookup based on ids is going to happen and convert it to a character
 */
private static Map<String, String> mLookupMap;

/**
 * I am not 100% sure if this is needed, but because we will be attempting to write to the mInputQueue,
 * and read from it, i've created a lock
 */
private static final Object mLock = new Object();

/**
 * Where we are going to store the input generated by button presses
 */
private Queue<Integer> mInputQueue= new LinkedList<>();

/**
 * Android Handler class to help with the timer, and executing our runnable to handle the
 * button resolution
 */
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

/**
 * Runnable to cause the application to check if there is valid input
 */
private Runnable mHandleInputRunnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttons);

    // method call to initialize the lookup map
    initializeLookup();

    // Obtain all the references from the layout that we are going to need to use
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    mButton00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0_0);
    mButton10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1_0);
    mButton01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0_1);
    mButton11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1_1);
    mButton02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_0_2);
    mButton12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1_2);

    // above, the activity implements the OnClickListener interface, set the activity to handle
    // the clicks of all of the buttons
    mButton00.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton10.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton01.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton11.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton02.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton12.setOnClickListener(this);

    // initialize the Runnable to do what we need it to do when we get a 'tick'
    mHandleInputRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handleAlarmTrigger();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (null != mInputQueue) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mInputQueue.add(v.getId());
        }
    }
    resetHandler();
}

/**
 * Helper method to do the initialization of the map. Sorry about the order for the button
 * presses. They are a little sporadic, no real rhyme or reason.
 */
private void initializeLookup() {
    if (null != mLookupMap) {
        return;
    }

    mLookupMap = new HashMap<>();

    /*
    1 button characters, use String.valueOf() instead of buildStringFromIds() as there is only
    one id
     */
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_0_0), "A");
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_1_0), "B");
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_0_1), "C");
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_1_1), "D");
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_0_2), "E");
    mLookupMap.put(String.valueOf(R.id.button_1_2), "F");

    /*
    2 button characters
     */

    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_0), "G");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_1), "H");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_1), "I");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_2), "J");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_2), "K");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0), "L");

    /*
    3 button characters
     */
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_0_1), "M");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_0_2), "N");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_1_1, R.id.button_1_2), "O");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_1_2), "P");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_0_1), "Q");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_0_1), "R");

    /*
    4 button characters
     */
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0), "S");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_1_0), "T");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_0_2, R.id.button_0_1), "U");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_1_1, R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_1_1), "V");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_0_2), "W");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_1_2, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_1_2), "X");

    /*
    5 button characters
     */

    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_0_0), "Y");
    mLookupMap.put(buildStringFromIds(R.id.button_0_0, R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_0_1, R.id.button_1_0, R.id.button_1_1), "Z");
}

/**
 * Helper method to poll all of the values out of the queue, and create a key. This may or may
 * not be a valid key into the map. It depends on the button presses.
 *
 * @param queue the input queue where we store the id correlating to the button that was pressed
 * @return String representing a key into the map
 */
private String buildStringFromQueue(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (null != queue) {
        Integer pollValue;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            while ((pollValue = queue.poll()) != null) {
                sb.append(pollValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Helper method to turn 1 to many R.id.button* into a string for a key as a lookup for a character
 * value
 *
 * The "..." means that the method can accept 1 or more values of the defined type
 *
 * @param ids 1 or more ids
 * @return String representing the ids as key into the map
 */
private String buildStringFromIds(int... ids) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int id : ids) {
        sb.append(id);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Helper method that is called each time there is a button click to either start or re-start
 * the time before resolving input
 */
private void resetHandler() {
    // null checks for the values we will be operating on
    if (null != mHandler && null != mHandleInputRunnable) {
        /**
         * remove the current runnable the handler may/may not have set, and reset it with the
         * delay. This is essentially resetting the time before the app takes the button press
         * and tries to do a lookup in the map.
         */
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandleInputRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandleInputRunnable, INPUT_HANDLE_DELAY_MS);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method that is called from the Runnable to attempt to handle the input
 */
private void handleAlarmTrigger() {
    // just to be safe, always check the queue for null, and don't handle if empty. Also
    // we will be setting values on the EditText, ensure it is non-null as well
    if (null != mEditText &&
            null != mInputQueue &&
            !mInputQueue.isEmpty()) {

        // Obtain the key from the input we have stored. This will provide a look up into the
        // map
        String mapKey = buildStringFromQueue(mInputQueue);

        // only try and append this if it was a valid set of button presses, and the map
        // actually has a value
        if (null != mapKey &&
                !mapKey.isEmpty() &&
                mLookupMap.containsKey(mapKey)) {
            mEditText.append(mLookupMap.get(mapKey));
        }

        // remove all stored values from the queue so we may restart the button presses
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mInputQueue.clear();
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

**Android Layout -- buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_0_0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_1_0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_0_1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_1_1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_0_2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_1_2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight=".5"
        android:layout_rowWeight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Hello may I ask question? I have two EditText, if I want to transfer to another EditText how is that possible ? And also If I have to perform a "send function?" using the buttons how is that possible sir? PS: I already have a CODES for send all I need is to perform it using by buttons.

Comment: @pjforum If I am understanding you correctly, you are asking if you put in a sequence of button presses, it will move/copy the entered text from one EditText to a different EditText?

Comment: It will not move/copy the entered text from one Edit Text to different EditText. What I want is just move to another editText and again input values/data.

Comment: @pjforum, what you are referring to is called focus. Check the Android developer docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus(). Next, you'll need to do a check in handleAlarmTrigger() for that sequence. If it is detected, you can requestFocus() on the new EditText, if not, you can proceed to try and resolve the button presses to a lookup in the Map.