# Android: Hash map, sequence or switch statement? [Java]

Tags: java, android

I am kinda confused, because someone told me to use Hash map in implementing my application, while the other one it is more wiser to use sequence, while my friend told me to implement it using switch statement..

---

So I have two questions:

First, what's the main difference between those three?

And the second one, What is the best way to use in my application? **[see reference below]**

Reference: [Android: Tapping one to six buttons continuously [one after another] to string together different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t)

Comment: It depends on which you need most, memory allocation, operation speed or coding efficiency

Comment: *Curious:* I know the [`HashMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) class and Java [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement. What is this `sequence` you are referring to? Is that an Android class?

Comment: @S.W. coding efficiency and operation speed. I just want to finish my application.

Comment: They are not comparable things.. `HashMap` is a data structure which allows you to store data as key value pairs while `switch` is a code block which is essentially a replacement for multiple `if.. else if ... else` conditions. Not sure what you mean by sequence since there's no such built in data type in Java

Comment: @pjforum I think there is not conflict to apply HashMap and switch together as HashMap is a kind of memory allocation method, and switch is conditional statement picking method, for sequence, i just guess it as an order algorithm or simply array stuff?
If I were you, I would simple HashMap<Integer, String> for resourceId of button & string and simply apply switch resId case

Comment: @pjforum
Code sample:
In onCreate, findViewById(<resId>).setOnClickListener(this);
In onClickListener, switch(v.getId()) , and currentString += map.get(<resId>), etc.
p.s. Use the switch only if you have other onClick event beside from those buttons, otherwise, simply put currentString += map.get(v.getId());