# Android: Processing input using Hashmap

Tags: java, android

This native braille app I am making has 6 different buttons that I would like to have every unique combination bring me different letters. For example: I would like hitting button 1 to simple bring me the letter "A". Then hitting button 1 and button 2 continuously brings me the letter "C". I want every different button combination of these 6 buttons to bring me a seperate letter.

But I am having hard time processing the input using hashmaps, can someone correct me what's need to be done? Thank you.

---

I've already collected the input data.

[image]

on my `onCreate()`

```
    txtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSMS);
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block3);
    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block4);
    Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block5);
    Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block6);


    // Attached Click Listener
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMesssage);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFour.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFive.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSix.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then the next one is to add a button press handler, add a countdown timer. With every button press, cancel the timer and start a new one. Which is:

```
final HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Timer processTimer = new Timer();


    processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {    
            processInput();    
        }

        private void processInput() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             hmap.put([R.id.block1], "A");               //<-------THIS
             hmap.put([R.id.block1],[R.id.block2], "C"); //<-------THIS

        }
    }, 500); // Delay before processing. 

processTimer.cancel();

processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {    
            processInput();    
        }

        private void processInput() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, 500); 
}
```

Then inside the processInput() - as you can see

- creating key/values in pairs, but I am getting errors when trying to initiate in processInput()
- So my another question is how to process input using the android buttons to display in textview?

EDIT: `The method put(String, String) in the type Map<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)` --> it is basically asking for changing the data type `int` to `string`, but when I do the "r.java.file" won't let it.

My reference is: [Android: Tapping one to six buttons continuously [one after another] to string together different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t)

Comment: Well for starters this `hmap.put([R.id.block1],[R.id.block2], "C");` does not really work. the `put` method only takes a key and a value as parameter. `R.id.something` is an `int` value so if you want to store that in a `HashMap` you need to use a `HashMap<Integer, String>` instead of `<String, String>`.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp I already tried that Hashmap<Integer, String> hcombined = new HashMap<String, String>(); I now got the error on "new Hashmap <String, String>, and if I tried to change the String into integer it will turn "yellow"

Comment: It has to look like this: `Hashmap<Integer, String> hcombined = new HashMap<>();` or `Hashmap<Integer, String> hcombined = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`.

Comment: I did that, but when I add another "button" it will prompt an error, it must just be only "Remove argument to match 'put(Integer,string)'". Then so I tried to add Hashmap<Integer,integer, string> then the error will be passed to "Hashmap" @NielsMasdorp

Comment: There is no such thing as a `HashMap<Integer, Integer, String>`. A map only has a key and a value. If you want multiple buttons as a key you could use a `List` as the key for the `HashMap`? Like this: `Map<List<Integer>, String> = new HashMap<>();`, but I suggest you do some reading on what a `HashMap` does and how it can be used.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp I tried the `List` but it prompts an error at `r.java.file` it tried changing from `int` to `list int` so it gets an error