# Android: Hashmap or Sequence in Java

Tags: java, android

What is more appropriate to use to implement [to create key/values and to process the input] in my application based on the reference [---> Here <---](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t)

These two were provided to me by different users, so I am hoping someone could tell me what's good to use in terms of **operation speed** and **coding efficiency**

Using the `sequence`, but though I am still having hard time implementing it.

```
//Those are fields:
private final List<List<String>> sequences;
private final List<String> currentSequence;

//This is a method you'll have to call from onCreate
private void initSequences(){
  sequences = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

  sequences.add(Arrays.asList("button1")); //A
  sequences.add(Arrays.asList("button1", "button3")); //B
  sequences.add(Arrays.asList("button1", "button2")); //C
```

...}

```
// This goes where you do the timer thing
currentSequence= new ArrayList<String>();
// For every new timer you must add the to the list the keypress
currentSequence.add(/*the key you registered*/);
// When a timer finishes its time and you finished to register the keypresses, lets say we will print the output letter with a syso
if(sequences.contains(currentSequence)){
  System.out.println( sequences.indexOf(currentSequence)+97 );
 } else {
  System.out.println( "sequence not correct" );
 }
 currentSequence.clear();
```

or using `map`, but the thing is this is just a pseudocode which was provided to me. I don't know how to implement it..

```
map = {[R.id.block1],'A',
[R.id.block1, R.id.block2],'B',
[R.id.block1, R.id.block2, R.id.block2],'C',
etc...
}
```

So I have done the following steps already

- 1. Collect your input data (the button taps)
- 2. Know when it's time to process the input
- 3. Then the last one to use (Map or Sequence) the processing of input.

I can't get it. :( Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You should re-phrase your question by clearly highlighting your problems. I can't understand your problem after reading this question.

Comment: @user2004685 yes I've done it. Thank you for your word.

Comment: The choice between `HashMap` and `ArrayList` basically depends on your application needs and the operations you'll be performing. For example, if you are concered about the order of the objects then you should look at the `List` instead of a `Map` but on the other hand if you want to perform a search then it's better to go with a `Map` as it will be more efficient in this case.

Comment: @user2004685 Did you see the reference I linked? That's the application that I am developing. I just want to finish my application I don't care about the coding efficiency, just the operation speed.

Comment: Quoting your words from the question, *"I am hoping someone could tell me what's good to use in terms of **operation speed** and **coding efficiency**"*

Comment: @user2004685 sorry my bad. They are both useful in implementing my application. What I really meant is that I just want to finish my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the best thing to use in case of Key-->Value pairs, you should check `ArrayMaps`, which are designed for this. They are similar to `HashMaps`, but more memory efficient.

- [Android Dev - ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html)

You can check this Example here:

- [ArrayMap Android example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.util.ArrayMap)

Just in case, here is also an example of `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("145", "PentHouse");
map.put("125", "BoardRoom");
map.put("145", "PentHouse");

String room = map.get("8");
// room will be null if "8" isn't a key in the map.
```

Example with `List` in `HashMap` (for arrays is similar):

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
map.put("Something", new ArrayList<Integer>());
for (int i=0;i<lenghtOfList; i++) {
    map.get("Something").add(item[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the examples, but when I tried combining the buttons in android, it prompts an error. Like instead of "145" I input "R.id.block1,R.id.block2" **based on reference -> see to understand** even if I change the <String> to <Integer> when it comes to combination it won't let me.

Comment: What does it mean it won't let you? What does it say?  R.id.block1 is ussually of integer type, yes. So you'd need `Map<String, int> `

Comment: Yes I tried that, but when I add another "R.id.block 2" That's a combination of buttons, then it prompts an error. `map.put(R.id.block1,R.id.block2, R.id.block4, "C");`

Comment: You cannot do it like you shown here. In Maps you can only put Key-->Value pairs. So like `map.put(R.id.block1, "A");` and not more. Or define a Map like `Map<int[], String>` and try puttinf those blocks as integer array.

Comment: So does that mean that I can't implement combination of buttons? That's what I'm wanting in my application.. Well I tried the "int[]" but I get this error `The method put(int[], String) in the type Map<int[],String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, String)` --> still..

See my reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t

This is what I am implementing..

Comment: Check my example for List of Integers and try it. But it seems you want some dynamic approach to add more items to HashMap than first defined. This could get tricky.

Comment: It still prompts an error sadly regarding the List<Integer>> the `R.java.file` won't let it

Comment: What about if you try to wrap block in getResources().getInteger(R.id.block12); ?

Answer (score 0):

It is much faster to use a `HashMap` than to search through an `ArrayList` of `Arrays` every time. I would put the key of the `HashMap` as a concatenation of your button numbers, and then I would put the value as the alphanumeric character. So your HashMap would be `<String, String>`, and a sample value in the Map would be `["13": "B"]`. When checking if the button combination was valid, you would check if `hashmap.get(buttonComboString) != null`.

Comment: Hello sir, I tried that instead of "13" I put "R.id.block1" but when I combine the "R.id.block1,R.id.block2" I get error. For example: `map.put(R.id.block1,R.id.block2, R.id.block4, "C");`

Comment: Yeah, you are not able to combine the id's in that way. I would suggest you create some other method that returns a String like "13" directly, but if you wanted to use ID's, you could try something like `map.put(getString(R.id.block1) + getString(R.id.block2), "C")`.

Comment: Uhmm that doesn't prompt error anymore, but the thing is when I tried clicking the buttons the application will automatically "Unfortunately, <appname> has stopped"

Comment: Can you by any chance edit your answer, then try copying some codes in here: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t **to implement that**

Comment: What is the error message you are getting when you run the app? You need to debug it as you run it so that you can see why it closes.

Comment: Well I don't know if I implemented it right. I put it on `onClick()` then I declared it in `Timer and TimerTask` then in `processInput()` I implement the `map.put(getString(R.id.block1), "A":`? is that correct?

Comment: The error was too many and the one I see is about `Timer has canceled` it is mostly about the timer and `view.performClick`

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to display it in Textview sir?

Comment: I think any errors with `Timer` should be put in another StackOverflow question. This question was just about the HashMap vs Array data structures. The syntax for an insert into your HashMap looks like `map.put(getString(R.id.block1), "A");` You can view the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Well in `map.put(getString(R.id.block1) + getString(R.id.block2), "C");` does that mean I have to click `block1` and `block2` to generate a letter "C" in textview yes? Or ?