# Android: Multiple buttons continuously tapped using Timertask/timer

Tags: java, android

This Braille app I am making has 6 different buttons that I would like to have every unique combination bring me different letters. For example: I would like hitting button 1 to simple bring me the letter "A". Then hitting button 1 and button 2 continuously brings me the letter "C". I want every different button combination of these 6 buttons to bring me a seperate letter.

The problem with my code is that when I tried clicking buttons "the app automatically stopped and exit" So I was wondering what's wrong with my timer code? And did the `map` inside the `processInput()` is good?

My other post (reference): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514223/android-tapping-one-to-six-buttons-continuously-one-after-another-to-string-t)

My `onClick` code:

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        Timer processTimer = new Timer();
        processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1), "A");
                map.put(getString(R.id.block1) + getString(R.id.block2), "C");



            }
        }, 500); // Delay before processing. 

    processTimer.cancel();

    processTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {    
                processInput();    
            }

            private void processInput() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                map.get(R.id.block1);
                map.get(R.id.block1+R.id.block2);
                //this.close();


            }
        }, 500);
}
```

Logcat:

```
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): Process: info.androidhive.speechtotext, PID: 31053
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:558)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:456)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at info.androidhive.speechtotext.Braillekeyboard.onClick(Braillekeyboard.java:305)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19900)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
01-13 03:47:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```